# moving averages then binarise if > then MA

Tags: r, date, zoo

I currently have hourly temperature data for the whole year. a small subset of it is here

```
Date     Temp
1/1/21   11
2/1/21   12
3/1/21   13
4/1/21   14
5/1/21   15
6/1/21   10
7/1/21   11
8/1/21   12
9/1/21   16
10/1/21  15
```

From this very community, I know to calculate moving averages, I would do

```
matemp <- zoo::rollmean(x = df$Temp, k = 2, align = "left", fill = NA )
```

Q1: if I want the new df displayed, would it be

```
newdf <- c(df, matemp)
```

This will produce a list not a vector?

I understand there is a difference in length but not sure what people do to deal with it.

Q2: From here, I'm hoping to identify outliers using the following criteria, if the temperature is larger than MA then return a 1 otherwise return 0. Would piping makes the most amount of sense here?

The final df should hopefully have the following columns:
Date
Temp
MA
Binary

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need *cbind* instead of *c*:

```
matemp <- zoo::rollmean(x = df$Temp, k = 2, align = "left", fill = NA )

# use cbind to add new columns, then assign to a newdf
newdf <- cbind(df, MA = matemp, Binary = as.integer(matemp < df$Temp))

newdf
#          Date Temp   MA Binary
# 1  2021-01-01   11 11.5      0
# 2  2021-01-02   12 12.5      0
# 3  2021-01-03   13 13.5      0
# 4  2021-01-04   14 14.5      0
# 5  2021-01-05   15 12.5      1
# 6  2021-01-06   10 10.5      0
# 7  2021-01-07   11 11.5      0
# 8  2021-01-08   12 14.0      0
# 9  2021-01-09   16 15.5      1
# 10 2021-01-10   15   NA     NA
```

Comment: Transform would also work following the creation of `matemp`... `transform(df, MA = matemp, Binary = as.integer(matemp < df$Temp))`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply attach the new vectors to your dataframe, i.e.

```
df$MA <- zoo::rollmean(x = df$Temp, k = 2, align = "left", fill = NA )
df$Binary <- as.integer(df$MA < df$Temp)

df
#      Date Temp   MA Binary
#1   1/1/21   11 11.5      0
#2   2/1/21   12 12.5      0
#3   3/1/21   13 13.5      0
#4   4/1/21   14 14.5      0
#5   5/1/21   15 12.5      1
#6   6/1/21   10 10.5      0
#7   7/1/21   11 11.5      0
#8   8/1/21   12 14.0      0
#9   9/1/21   16 15.5      1
#10 10/1/21   15   NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like this i suggest unsing tidyverses dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

# data
df <- 
  tibble(Date = seq(from = as.Date('2021-01-01'), to = as.Date('2021-01-10'), by=1),
         Temp = c(11,12,13,14,15,10,11,12,16,15))

# calculations
df %>% 
  mutate(MA = (Temp + lead(Temp)) / 2,
         outlier = if_else(Temp > MA, 1L, 0L))
```

Comment: You could use `1 * (Temp > MA)` as a simple alternative to this `if_else`-statement, but your MA doesn't match OP's `matemp`.

Comment: Thx @MartinGal, I misinterpreted the rollmean statement.  Now my calculations match the OP's (although I'm not sure whether this calcualtion is intended?)